# Lenovo IdeaPad tablet K1 but there no place for a SIM card

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Hello I just got a Lenovo IdeaPad tablet K1 but there no place for a SIM card but it is  Wi-Fi and that works but i want to know if I can add a wireless network adapter of some kind to get it to work in a park or in a place were there no
Wi-Fi is there any thing I can do or use to get it to work with out the Wi-Fi but still get online thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a [MiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiFi), or other mobile Wi-Fi router. These use the mobile networks for data and provide you a WiFi connection to use almost anywhere.

Alternatively you can tether it to your mobile phone if you have a smartphone and can make it act as a WiFi hotspot.

None of your questions are about Ubuntu though, are you planning on installing Ubuntu on the device? It's an Android tablet and your question would probably be a better fit on an [Android forum](https://android.stackexchange.com/)  .